# How to get data from form to controller using ajax in yii framework

Tags: php, ajax, drop-down-menu, yii

Hi iam new for yii framework. I am creating two dynamic dropdown based on first dropdown i want to show second dropdown. and also i want to do validation for this both dropdown. so how to pass id from form to controller and how to validate it? Please help me my form code is

```
echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'classid',CHtml::listData(Classdetails::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>"classid >0 and School_Id='$School' and Status=1","order"=>"classid")),'classid','classname'),
     array(
     'empty'=>'--Select a Class--',
     'ajax' => array(
     'type'=>'POST', //request type
     'url'=>CController::createUrl('Ptempnotification/Dynamiccities'), 
     'update'=>'#pid',      
     )));
    echo $form->error($model,'classid');
 echo $form->labelEx($model,'pid');
 echo CHtml::dropDownList('pid','', array());   
 echo $form->error($model,'pid');
```

My controller code is

```
public function actionDynamiccities()
{

     $data = Puserprofile::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('classid' => $_POST['classid']));
    $data=CHtml::listData($data,'pid','username');
    foreach($data as $value=>$name)
    {
        echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
    }
}
```

Here dynamiccities function is calling but `$_POST['classid']` is passing null. Iam using yii framework 1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try like this,

```
echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'classid',CHtml::listData(Classdetails::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>"classid >0 and School_Id='$School' and Status=1","order"=>"classid")),'classid','classname'),
     array(
     'empty'=>'--Select a Class--',
     'ajax' => array(
     'type'=>'POST', //request type
     'url'=>CController::createUrl('Ptempnotification/Dynamiccities'), 
      'data'=>array('classid'=>'js: $(this).val()'),
     'update'=>'#pid',      
     )));
```

Comment: if i not select means it is showing Undefined index: classid. if i select means the another dropdown is not showing

Comment: yes it is working how to validate second dropdown list  echo CHtml::dropDownList('pid','', array(), array('empty' => '-- Select Username --')); and how to get value in controller

Comment: use id of second dropdown list and get its value $('#pid').val()

Comment: Where i want to add this line can you explain more